# Integral of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{21t}{21+t^2}\cdot \cos(bt)\; \mathrm{d}t$ for $b\in\Bbb R$

Tags: integration

Please can you indicate to me a way for solving this integration? I used integration by parts, but the result's still complicated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What made the integration by parts difficult? Show us.

Comment: Are you sure it asks you to evaluate the integral?  (That is hard.)  Maybe it merely asks you to show the integral converges.  (That is easy.)

Comment: yes in deed should converge  @GEdgar but what's the expression, of course should contain the variable b.

Comment: Maybe if you told us why you need the "expression" then perhaps we would be able to understand and help you better .

Comment: @GEdgar. No so hard. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need something like Residue theorem.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{21t \cos(bt)}{t^2+21}dt=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{21t \cos(bt)}{t^2+21}dt=\frac12{\frak{Re}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{21t e^{ibt}}{t^2+21}dt$$

Now consider $\int \frac{21t e^{ibt}}{t^2+21}$ along a countour $\Gamma$ along the real line and then a semi-cirle in the upper-half plane. By the residue theorem, (with an enough circle radius to include the singularitie $\sqrt{21}i$), we have
$$\int_C \frac{21 e^{ibt}}{t^2+21}dt=2\pi i\lim_{t \to \sqrt{21}i}(t-\sqrt{21}i)\frac{t e^{ibt}}{(t-\sqrt{21}i)(t+\sqrt{21}i)}=21\pi i e^{-\sqrt{21}b} $$

First you need to prove that as the radius of the upper semicirle arc goes to infinity, the countour along the arc goes to zero. So we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{t e^{ibt}}{t^2+21}dt=21\pi i e^{-\sqrt{21}i} $$
Hence
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{21 \cos(bt)}{t^2+21}dt=\frac12{\frak{Re}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{21 e^{ibt}}{t^2+21}dt={\frak{Re}}(\frac{21\pi i e^{-\sqrt{21}}}{2})=0$$

Comment: I think that we disagree.

Comment: I disagree the first step when you change the bounds. It is evident that from $-\infty$ to $ +\infty $ the integral result should be  nul

Answer (score 2):

Consider instead
$$I=\int\frac{a^2 t }{t^2+a^2}\cos (b t)\,dt$$ Write
$$\frac{a^2 t }{t^2+a^2}=\frac{a^2 t }{(t+ia)(t-ia)}=\frac{a^2}2\Big[\frac{1}{t+ia} +\frac{1}{t-ia}\Big]$$ So, you have two integrals
$$I_\pm=\int \frac{\cos (b t)}{t\pm ia}\,dt$$ Consider the first
$$I_+=\int \frac{\cos (b t)}{t+ ia}\,dt$$ Let $x=t+i a$
$$I_+=\int  \frac{\cos (b t)}{t+ ia}\,dt=\int\frac{\cos (b (x-i a))}{x}\,dx$$Expand the cosine
$$\cos (b (x-i a))=\cosh (a b) \cos (b x)+i \sinh (a b) \sin (b x)$$
$$I_+=\cosh (a b)\int \frac {\cos (b x)}x \,dx+i \sinh (a b)\int \frac {\sin (b x)}x \,dx$$ Now $b x=y$
$$I_+=\cosh (a b)\int \frac {\cos (y)}y \,dy+i \sinh (a b)\int \frac {\sin (y)}y \,dy$$ and you face two well known trigonometric integrals $\text{Ci}(y)$ and $\text{Si}(y)$

Doing the same for $I_-$ to obtain
$$I_-=\cosh (a b)\int \frac {\cos (y)}y \,dy-i \sinh (a b)\int \frac {\sin (y)}y \,dy$$

Using the bounds and getting rid of all complex numbers
$$\color{blue}{J=\int_0^\infty\frac{a^2 t }{t^2+a^2}\cos (b t)\,dt=a^2 (\text{Shi}(a b) \sinh (a b)-\text{Chi}(a b) \cosh (a b))}$$

Back to your previous question, the simplification of
$$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } a^2 G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{a^2 b^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0,0,\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right)$$ you obtained using Python leads to the same result.

**Edit**

If $$ab=0.879087753159252\cdots \sim \frac{-85+569 e+517 e^2}{454+464 e+581 e^2}$$ the result is almost $0$ (more precisely $-1.124\times 10^{-21}$)